# What if Mars and Venus are habitable

Tags: alternate-reality

What if both planets (Venus and Mars) have atmospheres, tons of water, life on them, and much more to make them habitable planets.

Comment: We could ship the feminists to Venus and the MRAs to Mars, making three planets inhabited by people who are much happier than before.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2):

The US or Russia would have probably sent probes and maybe even astronauts to these planets, that could have even extended the space race.
These planets would have a great possibility for life to arise on them if not spontaneously by means of life dissemination through asteroids, if the panspermia theory is right. However, even though the life forms in each planet would have come from the same origin, nowadays they would be very different from each other due to the many differences in Mars' and Venus' environments.

Answer (score 1):

More seriously than in my comment:

**People who want to get away**

There will be movements, of varying sizes, consisting of people who are disaffected by whatever society they are part of here on Earth, and would be trying to gather the resources and technology to start a new community on whichever planet they prefer.  Think of space ships named 'Mayflower', but instead of Puritans, each group would consist of libertarians, communists, persecuted minority sects of Islam, black nationalists, white supremacists, people who think *Star Trek* is a documentary, etc.

**Worried Governments**

The governments of Earth, frantically afraid that this might lead to an independent nation that is militarily more powerful than they are, or lead to a rival nation having a leg up on the rest, would do everything in their power to ensure that colonization either does not take place or takes place on their terms.

**The United Nations**

The U.N. will claim all authority over any extra-terrestrial human activities.  Soft-headed people in western democracies will take this idea seriously.  Dictatorships will pretend to take this idea seriously while brow-beating western democracies, but will ignore the idea entirely in practice.

**"Hands Off The Other Planets" Movements**

These people will claim that raping the environment of one planet is surely enough, and oppose any exploration or colonization of the pristine wildernesses of either planet.

**Venus/Mars Deniers**

The natural allies of the people who claim that the moon landing was a hoax, these people will claim that the reports of life sustainability on the other planets are all lies.  The explanation for why the government is going to the trouble of crafting this lie will vary, but at least on group will claim that it's a plot to liquidate undesirables under the ruse of sending them to colonize the other planets.

**Ship the ____ to Venus/Mars**

As a "humane" alternative to a second Holocaust, there will be voices calling for the shipment of minority groups to whichever other planet is least hospitable.  Finally, we can get rid of the Christians/atheists/Muslims/Kaffirs/gays/homophobes/communists/capitalists/Trump supporters/Hillary supporters/etc.

**Colonialism was Awesome, Let's do it Again!**

We get even more complexity if Mars and Venus are inhabited by intelligent life.  In addition to every well-connected person wanting to go over there and exploit them for their own benefit, every ideologue of every stripe will want to go there and teach the natives about Jesus/Muhammed/Marx/capitalism/the healing power of lesbianism/etc.

Oh, and alien porn, too.  Don't forget that.  (Although it probably will be something best forgotten...)

Comment: Dissaffected movements typically do not have the resources needed for space exploration (if they had, they would have already used it to influence society their way and would no longer be "dissaffected). Comparing the cost of space exploration with the cost of fleeting a wooden ship of about 180 tons (in an age when wooden ships of that size were very common)-> -1.